# Can't group by a column (Business Area) in my document library

Tags: column, filter

Business Area is a required column in my doc library. It's set up as "Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)". I have created several views, and in some of them I want the option to group by that column. However, it is not an option. Here's the reason I need that: In each view I am using the filter "Show items only when the following is true" for this column - but rather than using "is equal to" I need to use "contains" due to the multiple selections. That's fine, except that two of the Business Areas are Sales and Sales Associates. If I make it "contains Sales" it will bring up docs related to both, so I need to be able to group the display by Business Area to keep them separate. Can you tell me if there's a way to do what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a separate view for each Business Area that is grouped by Sales Associates.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this one. I already have a separate view for each Business Area, but it seems only certain columns are available in the "group by" list. Does it have anything to do with the fact that this is a different document library from the default Shared Documents? (i.e., it is one I created)

Comment: The problem with group by is that you are only able to have an item listed once in the same view.  So the multi-select choice column will not work.  The views are the way to deal with that.  Then make a link list of the views, or add them to the quick launch.

Comment: That sounds right. I will work on that. Thanks for your help, Jammin4CO!